# Compute property only once

Tags: kotlin

Given the following code

```
class A
class B {
    val property: A
        get() = A()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = B()
    println(b.property)
    println(b.property)
}
```

It returns a new `A` instance every time `B.property`. Is there an easy way to make it return the same instance every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use delegated properties [lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) simply, for example:

```
class B {
    val property by lazy(::A)
}
```

You can also use a lambda expression instead like this:

```
class B {
    val property by lazy { A() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in this way:

```
object A
class B {
    val property: A
        get() = A
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = B()
    println(b.property) // >>> A@3cd1a2f1
    println(b.property) // >>> A@3cd1a2f1
}
```

Comment: Good idea though I can't make it a object

Comment: Then use lazy properties as @holi-java suggested :)

Comment: Yeah I think I will. I thought there is a more convenient way to do this though.

Comment: @Mibac I find the lazy-delegate very convenient. What is your concern?